# Ruby: calling 'join' after a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm watching a RailsCast (#101) in which the authoruses some methods to make a star rating system for a blog.  In the method `star_image`s, he calls join on the end of a block.  I think this turns an array into a string, but why would that need to be done?

**View**

```
<%= render_stars(product.rating) %>
```

**Application_helper.rb**

```
 def render_stars
    content_tag :div, star_images, :class => 'stars'
  end
```

private

```
 def star_images
    (0...5).map do |position|
      star_image(((@rating-position)*2).round)
    end.join
  end

  def star_image(value)
    image_tag "/images/#{star_type(value)}_star.gif", :size => '15x15'
  end

  def star_type(value)
    if value <= 0
      'empty'
    elsif value == 1
      'half'
    else
      'full'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `star_image` method produces a single string with a single img tag in it.  The `star_images` method is supposed to return a single string with 5 img tags in it.

If the author didn't call join in `star_images`, then `star_images` would return an array with 5 strings in it, and that might cause unexpected behavior.  In general if you have a helper function that produces some HTML, it should return it as a string (not an array).  By calling `join`, he concatenates all 5 strings together into one string and that's the string that gets returned.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: The result should be String, not an array.

The reason behind may be a change of ruby 1.8 to 1.9.

Take this code example:

```
puts ['a', 'b']
puts ['a', 'b'].to_s 
puts "#{['a', 'b']}"
```

With ruby 1.8 you get:

```
a
b
ab
ab
```

(I hope I'm correct. I have no ruby 1.8 version available).

With ruby 1.9 you get:

```
a
b
["a", "b"]
["a", "b"]
```

`Array#to_s` is `Array#inspect` since ruby 1.9. If you need a 'readable', not-technical String-representation you should use `Array#join`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is a concatenation of 5 "img" Blocks.

"star_image" returns a new string which contains one "img" block for one star image. This is called for each array element (0...5).map and with join these single star images are returned in one long string.

/edit

The reason why this is done is simply because the helper method shall insert these image blocks into the view. Of course you could do it otherwise, like returning an array and do the string generation within the view, but that wouldn't make sense and is not a good style.